# JSF: javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot add the same component twice: vaz4n2-retrieve-update

Tags: jsf, eclipse-plugin, icefaces-3

I am a JSF beginner. I try to implement ICEfaces 3.0 component in Eclipse 4.2 (Juno). I had implemented & run it using Apache Tomcat 7.0. It showing the following error in window:

> Cannot add the same component twice

In console bar it shows as :

```
javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot add the same component twice: v8z4ho2-retrieve-update
```

My JSF Code

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:icecore="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/core"  
    xmlns:ace="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/components"   
    xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component" >

<h:head>
    <title>Chart</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./xmlhttp/css/rime/rime.css"/>
</h:head>

<h:body styleClass="ice-skin-rime">     
    <h:form id="canvasForm">
        <ace:chart id="chart" animated="false" value="#{chartBean.barData}"
            stackSeries="false" defaultAxesConfig="#{chartBean.barDemoDefaultAxis}"
            xAxis="#{chartBean.barDemoXAxis}" yAxis="#{chartBean.barDemoYAxis}"
            legend="true"  legendPlacement="OUTSIDE_GRID" highlighter="true"
            highlighterLocation="N" highlighterShowMarker="false"       
            highlighterBringSeriesToFront="true"
            widgetVar="barChart" />
    </h:form>    
</h:body>
</html>
```

How to rectify this error? Help me out.

Comment: @BeginnerJava: library/framework/API names like "ICEFaces", "Tomcat", etc are NOT code! Please stop incorrectly formatting them as code in suggested edit.

Comment: @BalusC I edited because I had seen it used in several posts as a way to highlight the important words, (and I found it helpful to got through the posts). Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @BeginnerJava: Read meta.stackoverflow.com on tag [review-abuse].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ICEFaces forum I've found many people with this problem. If you are using Tomcat 7.0.42, try Tomcat 7.0.41 instead and see if it works. Also check if you have icefaces jar duplicated (or icefaces.jar and icefaces-ee.jar) in the same classpath. The link to the post is:

http://www.icesoft.org/JForum/posts/list/22121.page#sthash.qxEkXX1Q.dpbs

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by reverting icefaces version from 3.3.0 to 3.0.1:

```
    <!-- Ices Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>icefaces</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>icefaces-ace</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>icefaces-compat</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.icepush</groupId>
        <artifactId>icepush</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```